# For $X = (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ i.i.d. $N(0,\theta),$ show $ T = \bar X $ is not complete for $\theta$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

For $X = (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ i.i.d. $N(0,\theta),$ show $ T = \bar X $ is not complete for $\theta$.

**Definition:** Let f (t, θ), θ ∈ Θ be a family of distributions for a statistic T (X). The family is called complete if $E_θg(T) = 0$ for all θ ∈ Θ implies $P_θ(g(T) = 0) = 1$ for all θ ∈ Θ. Equivalently, T(X) is called a complete statistic for θ.

I let $g(T)=t=\bar X$.

$E(g(T))=E(\bar X)=0 \quad   $    (fairly obvious)

But how do I show g(T) is not identically zero everywhere.

Comment: You might define what it means for a random variable to be complete for a parameter.

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\bar X$ is a (scaled) sum of i.i.d. normally distribtued variables, so is also normally distributed. In particular, the probability that it takes the value $0$ is $0$, not $1$ as required.

Comment: Why is the probability of the average taking the zero value, zero?

Comment: @user538762: The normal distribution is a continuous distribution. The probability of a continuous distribution taking any particular value is always zero. If it's not obvious that this probability is zero, at least it should be obvious that it's not one, i.e. that a normal distribution can take values other than zero.